# Set Enable False ListItems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a RadioButtonList and ListItems attached to the RadioButtonList how can I set enable=false the ListItem on code behind cus I don't have id??

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSearchMode" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Location" Selected="True" Value="0" onclick="searchModeClick();"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Name" Value="1" onclick="searchModeClick();"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Take a look at Items collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable an item, find it using FindByText or FindByValue, then set the item's 'Enabled' property: -

```
    var item = rblSearchMode.Items.FindByText("By Location");

    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Enabled = false;
    }
```